# I can not get json data by spring mvc when controller redirect

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc

I want return json and html from spring mvc 
the spring config:(when controller is not redirect it is OK!)

```
<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
    <property name="ignoreAcceptHeader" value="true" />
    <property name="defaultContentType" value="text/html" />
    <property name="mediaTypes">
        <map>
            <entry key="json" value="application/json" />
            <entry key="xml" value="application/xml" />
        </map>
    </property>
    <property name="favorParameter" value="false" />
    <property name="viewResolvers">
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.BeanNameViewResolver" />
            <bean
                class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
                <property name="viewClass"
                    value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
                <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
                <property name="suffix" value=".jsp">
                </property>
            </bean>
        </list>
    </property>
            <!--  ............... -->
```

then controller :

```
@RequestMapping(value="test")
public ModelAndView test(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response){
    Result result = new Result(/*.......*/);
             //return 
             {
             //====>it is OK,when i call http://localhsot/test.json 
                ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("user/test","result",result);                       
                return mv; //
            }
            {
            //=====> it is also redirect,when i call  http://localhsot/test.json (response statues 302!)
                ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("redirect:user/test""result",result);
                return mv;
            }
}
```

How can i get json data when ModelAndView'view is redriect in my controller?

Comment: A redirect isn't going to work, a redirect means a new request to the server after the redirect. You might get it to work with `RedirectAttributes` and set them into the flash map. But all in all seems overly complex, why not simply let the 'user/test' page call another controller which returns a JSON response.

Comment: @M.Deinum sorry,maybe i made a mistake for my description.i mean that when controller redirect ,i can not get json data.(i had fix my question)

Comment: That I understood already and my comment still applies.

Comment: @M.Deinum  I just want to reduce duplication and redundancy of code,(The controller return html,at the same time may also be called by ajax)

Comment: And how would be 2 methods (1 returning the name of the view the other return json) be redundant? You just split the method in two, you only need to change your JSP.

Comment: @M.Deinum Although I also want to know if there are other way, but still thank you!!

Comment: Your current solution will onlyu work with redirect params incase of the redirect. But assuming that your `user/test` leads to a JSP which renders the JSON then your current setup is a bit strange imho.